# Dynamic rule validation persistence between validator calls

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I've came across this problem a few times, but could never find a solution, only work arounds.

Lets say I have multiple 10 jobs, but depending on the answers given the validation rules are different.

```
foreach($jobs as $job){

    if(!$this->Job->validates()){
        echo 'Oh no, it didn't validate';
    }

}
```

The main problem I'm finding is if I set a rule that was triggered only by the first job.

```
if($this->data['Job']['type'] == 'special'){
    $this->validator()->add('special_field', 'notEmpty', array(
        'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
        'message' => 'Please provide data'
    ));
}
```

It would also apply to the other 9. So the rules are persistent between calls. So can could remove the rule if it exists.

```
if($this->data['Job']['type'] == 'special'){
    $this->validator()->add('special_field', 'notEmpty', array(
        'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
        'message' => 'Please provide data'
    ));
}else{
    $this->validator()->remove('special_field', 'notEmpty');
}
```

But if the rule doesn't exist when it tries to remove it a Fatal Error is thrown.

Is there any way to check a rule exists before I remove it or a way to clear dynamic rules at the start of beforeValidate?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ModelValidator::getField` method to get all rules of a field and use that to check if a specific rule exists. [See](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#modifying-current-validation-rules).

Answer (score 0):

Interesting problem.

I have not tested this, but it seems that one can use:

```
$this->validator()->remove('special_field');
```

to remove all the rules for a field.

Comment: Other answer is correct. You need to check the rule exists before trying to remove it since a fatal error is throw if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Sure. I meant to say that when removing all rules, there's no error.